# jquery 1.4 incompatible with IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have 2 buttons. What I want is only after post successes enable these buttons in order to  keep data correct. The problem is, in one sentence, the jquery **attr("disabled", "disabled")** cannot work with IE10, but no problem with Chrome and Firefox at all.

But **attr("name")** functions normally.

Any comment is appreciated. Here is the code.

```
j$("div.document-list").find("input").live("click",function(){
    var move = j$(this).attr("name");
    //other code
    j$("div.document-list").find("input").attr("disabled","disabled");
    j$.ajax({
        //other code
        type   : "post",
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "1") {
                //other code
                j$("div.document-list").find("input").attr("disabled","");
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: IE supports Jquery 1.x branches.

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/9r3ra/

Comment: Is your site running in quirks mode or forced into IE 7 behaviour?

Comment: @Irvin Dominin aka Edward, jsfiddle doesn't seem to support jQuery1.4 :(

Comment: @Sarotti yes include it from a CDN not from the supported jsfiddle libraries, check out my fiddle

Comment: It can work with IE7, but meets problems when IE10 used

Comment: @Sarotti the fiddle too, or only your site? Can you share it or show a demo?

Comment: @Irvin Dominin aka Edward, ashamedly the function is a little complicated I don't know how to simulate it in fiddle. Simply speaking, the 2 buttons control the sort of uploaded files, on clicking them the new sort will be posted to php then the files' DB attributes will change.   And I tried **attr("disabled","")** **attr("disabled",false)** **removeAttr("disabled")**, all of them cannot work normally in IE10. So sad.

Comment: jQuery 1.4 is very old. I strongly recommend upgrading. My guess is that doing so will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
j$("div.document-list").find("input").prop("disabled",false);
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, jquery version currently used is 1.4, doesn't support prop();

Comment: @Sarotti Well, then it's probably the problem, since jQuery 1.4 is very old already and lack of a lot of features, the compatibility with modern browser is obvious IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably maybe actually works on IE 9 and older.

A reasons why this may not work is modern browsers is if it's forced into IE 7 behaviour:

1. A  tag may have been used to emulate IE7 (this was often used
   to keep working old sites)
2. Something else may have triggered quirks mode

You can checkout these problems, and consider to update your jQuery core library to a newer version and use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: sorry for replying so late. I guess I found the reason why it could not work. Image button disabled in IE seems to have problems, both in IE7 and IE10. The approach to solve my problem is by setting a flag, use **return** instead of disabling buttons. Sorry it's my fault that I didn't figure out the reasons.

Comment: @Sarotti what do you mean by __Image button__ can you show your HTML and CSS?